# Google App Script | Script in HTML Page can't call a function outside the html file or a function through library

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a problem where my script in HTML page can't call a function outside the HTML file or a function through the library. Here is the HTML code:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>Please enjoy this helpful script.</p>
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>

    <div>
      <label for="sheetLink">Google Sheets Link:</label>
      <input type="text" id="myInput">
      <button id="myButton" onclick="handleButtonClick()">Click me</button>
      
    </div>

    
    <script>
      function handleButtonClick() {
        var userInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
        console.log(userInput);
        alert(userInput)
        let uwow = LibIdentifier.receiveLink();
        Logger.log(uwow);
        console.log(uwow);
        alert(uwow)
        userClicked();
    }
    
    </script>

  </body>
</html>`
```

I Expect the code to receive variable uwow from another function, and then do alert from result.

I have tried using google.script.run.functionname(). But it does not work.

What actually resulted is an error like this:
[Error on Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M83Z5.png)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand of `a function outside the html file or a function through library` of `Google App Script | Script in HTML Page can't call a function outside the html file or a function through library` in your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Yes absolutely, sorry for the delayed response. So what I mean is that the script in the HTML file, can't call any function outside the HTML file.

Example: I have a function called receivedLink in another file.

function receiveLink() {
  var uwow = "function works"
  return uwow

}

So if i called this function from html file, the expected result should be an alert of text "function works" .

let me know i i can provide more info. Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming your HTML page is served through Google [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)., custom dialog, sidebar, doPost()?  If so you would need to  use [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) to access the library.

Comment: Also you would need to add the Library as a resource to your App Script project.

Comment: @TheWizEd yes, I used an HTML service, here is the doGet code:

function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page');
}"

I already installed a library and have tried using google.script.run to call a function in the library. But still, receive error : function is not defined".

here is my google.script.run code 

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).userClicked();

Comment: Hi Everyone thank you for helping me with this problem. I found the solution after asking the app script community. You can read the solution in this link:
https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/E05rum7jJcQ